# How to get yes/no attribute value in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I added an attribute test through admin panel, which can be set to yes/no value. I want to display the value of test whether it is set to yes or no. How can I do that?

I tried something like that:

```
<?php
 $attributeModel = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product','test');
 echo $attribute_value = $attributeModel->getStoreLabel($storeId);
 $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
 echo $_product->getData('test');
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This

```
echo $_product->getAttributeText('test');
```

Comment: Its always giving no value, even if I change value to yes @Piyush

Comment: ok I made some mistake. Its working. Thanks for the help @Piyush